# how can i get all Wed date during a selected period of time?

Tags: python

so i want to get all Wednesday date for a selected period, say all Wed between today to next Sep 19, 2020.

I figured out how to get all Wed from now to end of 2019 but don't know how to get further.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
def allweds(year):
    d =date(2019, 9, 24)                    
    d += timedelta(days = 6 - d.weekday()) 
    while d.year == year:
        yield d
        d += timedelta(days = 7)
for d in allweds(2019):
    print(d)
```

Hoping to get code to get all Wed between today and Sep 19, 2020. All another way all Wed for next 52 weeks. Thanks.

update: 
i sort of figured out how to get date of given weekday during a period of time: (thanks to C Perkins)

## get dates for all Weds from 2019.9.24 to 2020.9.19.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
enddate = date(2020, 9, 19)
def allWeds():
d = date(2019, 9, 24)
d += timedelta(days = 2 - d.weekday())
while d <= enddate:
    yield d
    d += timedelta(days = 7)
for d in allWeds():
    print(d, d.weekday())
```

Comment: What does this have to do with sqlite?  It is tagged as such, but it looks like code is all python.

Comment: The while loop is comparing values directly like `while d.year == year`, so it will apparently only ever continue for a single year value.  If you want it to go further, you need to add another parameter and compare those dates instead of just the year, something like `while d <= enddate` where enddate could be 2020-09-20.  If you want another condition, then make another function that counts (using an integer like `i`) and stops the loop when it reaches `i == 52`.  Although dates are involved, this is just an exercise in building different conditional statements for the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
def iter_wed(start, end):
    '''Yield all Wednesdays in a date range.'''
    date = start + datetime.timedelta((2 - start.weekday()) % 7)
    while date < end:
        yield date
        date += datetime.timedelta(7)
```

You could also extend it to work for any week day.

```
def iter_weekday(start, end, weekday=2):
    '''Yield all of a particular weekday in a date range.'''
    date = start + datetime.timedelta((weekday - start.weekday()) % 7)
    while date < end:
        yield date
        date += datetime.timedelta(7)
```